# Typescript chaining Promises

Tags: typescript, promise

If anyone can help with the following Typescript Error, I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

I am making use of the following [code](https://github.com/mirkonasato/ionix-sqlite/blob/master/src/SqlDatabase.ts) where it has the following. It needs to be able to chain the `Promise`.

```
line 26:    dbPromise = _db.execute(sql)
```

When I try build it, I get the following:

> ```
> ERROR in ./app/pages/chats/SqlDatabase.ts
> (26,9): error TS2322: Type 'Promise<SqlResultSet>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<SqlDatabase>'.
>   Type 'SqlResultSet' is not assignable to type 'SqlDatabase'.
>     Property '_db' is missing in type 'SqlResultSet'.
> ```

I am using `Typescript version 2.0.3.`

code:

```
import { isBrowser } from './platform';
import { SqlResultSet } from './SqlResultSet';

export class SqlDatabase {

  constructor(private _db: any) { }

  static open(name: string, initStatements: string[] = []): Promise<SqlDatabase> {
    let dbPromise = isBrowser()
      .then(browser => {
        const openDatabase = browser ? openBrowserDatabase : openCordovaDatabase;
        return openDatabase(name);
      });
    if (initStatements.length === 0) {
      return dbPromise;
    }
    let _db: SqlDatabase;
    // execute the first statement and capture the _db
    dbPromise.then(db => {
      _db = db;
      return db.execute(initStatements.shift());
    });
    // execute all the other statements (if any) sequentially
    for (let sql of initStatements) {
      dbPromise.then(() => {
        dbPromise = _db.execute(sql)
      });
    }
    // resolve the _db only after all statements have completed
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('resolve: ', resolve);
      dbPromise.then(() => resolve(_db)).catch(reject);
    });
  }

  execute(statement: string, params: any[] = []): Promise<SqlResultSet> {
    console.log('execute: ' + statement);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._db.transaction(tx => tx.executeSql(statement, params, (tx, resultSet) => {
        console.log('execute: resolve: ', resultSet);
        resolve(resultSet);
      }, (tx, error) => {
        reject(error)
      }));
    });
  }
}

declare var sqlitePlugin: any;

function openCordovaDatabase(name: string): Promise<SqlDatabase> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof sqlitePlugin === 'undefined') {
      reject(new Error('[ionix-sqlite] sqlitePlugin global object not found; did you install a Cordova SQLite plugin?'));
    }
    const db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
      name: name,
      location: 'default'
    });
    console.info('[ionix-sqlite] using Cordova sqlitePlugin');
    resolve(new SqlDatabase(db));
  });
}

declare function openDatabase(name: string, version: string, desc: string, size: number): any;

function openBrowserDatabase(name: string): Promise<SqlDatabase> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const db = openDatabase(name, '1.0', name, -1);
      console.info('[ionix-sqlite] using WebSQL');
      resolve(new SqlDatabase(db));
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! Just `return dbPromise.then(()=>_db)`.

Comment: Are you sure `isBrowser()` can't be synchronous? Returning a promise is the root of a lot of complication, which you should avoid if possible.

Comment: @Bergi can you avoid the promise antipattern in Typescript in this scenario though is the question

Comment: @BrianOgden Yes, you can always avoid the antipattern. What scenario do you refer to particularly?

Comment: Well in Typescript,an example would be an async function that returns Promise<MyObj> but say I do not want callers to reference MyObj class definition,so I wrap the async func in another Promise<MyObjViewModel>, make sense?

Comment: @Bergi does that scenario in my previous comment make sense?

Comment: @BrianOgden That sounds entirely like a type restriction on the public interface, and has nothing to do with the antipattern? But even if `MyObjViewModel` is a wrapper around `MyObj`, you don't have to use the `new Promise` constructor anywhere. You might want to [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your exact code if you're still not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you try to change the type of `dbPromise`.
When it is first declared:

```
let dbPromise = isBrowser()
      .then(browser => {
        const openDatabase = browser ? openBrowserDatabase : openCordovaDatabase;
        return openDatabase(name);
      });
```

the compiler refers the type to `Promise<SqlDatabase>` (based on the error), but then you try to assign something else:

```
dbPromise = _db.execute(sql)
```

which is of type `Promise<SqlResultSet>`.
You can solve it like so:

```
let dbPromise: Promise<any> = ...
```

Or you can have two different promise variables (i.e.: `dbPromise: Promise<SqlDatabase>` and `resultPromise: Promise<SqlResultSet>`) which sounds better to me.

Comment: `dbPromise = _db.execute(sql)` is completely wrong anyway. If the code is tidied into a sensible pattern, that line disappears.